# IIS6 hosts another site when going to https and the site doesn't have SSL

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ssl, iis-6

I've got a handful of sites on a windows 2003 IIS 6 box.  Many of the sites are configured using host name header.  A few of the sites have their own IP addresses, and have SSL certificates installed.  I'm finding that when I got to one of the non SSL host name header sites, and try to enter https, it serves up one of the SSL sites.

For instance:

site1.com - No SSL.  Bindings are:
IP: All Unassigned
TCP Port: 80
Host Header Value: site1.com

IP: All Unassigned
TCP Port: 80
Host Header Value: www.site1.com

sitez.com - SSL.  Bindings are:
IP: 192.168.100.73
TCP Port: 80
Host Header Value: empty
(This one also has SSL Port 443 on the Web Site tab)

Going to http://www.site1.com is fine, but going to https://www.site1.com hosts up sitez.com.  Everything else works as intended, but when the server gets a request for https on site1, it hosts up sitez.

I've tried changing from All Unassigned to the internal IP address for the server, but the same effect happens.

Answer (score 1):

When using the HTTPS protocol, the host headers are ignored (at least on IIS 6).  If you don't want this phenomenon to occur, then you will need to assign www.site1.com to a dedicated IP address, not using "All Unassigned", and do not use another SSL site on the same IP address.

Comment: Currently, each site with SSL has it's own unique IP.  No other sites share an IP with an SSL site - one IP per SSL site.  But I can't have each NON ssl site have it's own dedicated IP.  That defeats the point of Host Name Header.

Comment: Well, you can have all non-SSL sites share 1 IP address, just don't put SSL sites on that same IP.

Comment: We don't.  All SSL sites are on their own unique IP, and nothing else shares them.  The non ssl sites are all on "All Unassigned", which is on an entirely unique IP that isn't used by SSL based sites all all. That's where the confusion is coming from - everything is on their own IPs, aside from Non SSL sites, which are all sharing the same IP.  I'm not sure why going to https:// on a non SSL site is displaying a site that's on its own unique IP.